# Single Page application n-tier architecture using ASP.NET Web API and Angular

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

I have been assigned a project that needs to be implemented in a single page architecture. I have chosen ASP.NET Web API and Angular JS to start with. Here is the architecture of my application:

```
MyProject.Web: (ASP.NET Empty Application)
1). Entity Framework
2). ASP.NET Razor
3). ASP.NET Web Optimization
4). ASP.NET Web API

MyProject.DTO: (Class Library Project)
```

I am not sure if I should include reference to Entity Framework inside **MyProject.web**.
What more refinements you suggest I should make?

**EDIT**
I have made up my mind to use Entity Framework. With respect to Single Page Architecture, is it necessary to create a separate project (DAL) and reference Entity Framework DLL?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EntityFramework and BreezeJs may prove to be a lot of help. (depending on the scope/goal of your app)

Comment: breeze is a HUGE library with little benefits. You can manage your on client data management with far less code, trust me.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the reply. Can you suggest me some other client side data management library?

Comment: @Cory: I have updated my question. Can you please have a look once again? Thanks

Comment: If you want another opinion on whether to use Breeze or not, read John Papa's blog post: http://www.johnpapa.net/spajs04 - the 50+ comments from other developers are also worth a read.

Comment: It is not necessary but may prove to be useful in the future if another applications needs to use it (besides the SPA). For example we have separated out the DAL so an web service could archive uploaded files to Amazon.